# Matrix Equation, Product of Matrices should have specific form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Im currenty searching for matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$

such that $B \cdot A = \lambda_1 \cdot I_n + \lambda_2 \cdot 1^T1$ where  $I_n$ is the identity matrix and $1$ is a vector containing $n$ ones.

So the resulting matrix should look like this:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 & \lambda_2 & \dots & \lambda_2 \\
\lambda_2 & \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 & \dots & \lambda_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \lambda_2\\
\lambda_2 & \dots & \dots & \lambda_1 + \lambda_2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Im now trying to figure out what structure $A$ and $B$ need to have for this to work.
I of course noticed that
$$
\vec{B_{i,\cdot}} \cdot \vec{A_{\cdot, i}} = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2, \text{ for } 1 \leq i \leq n  
$$
and
$$
\vec{B_{i,\cdot}} \cdot \vec{A_{\cdot, j}} = \lambda_2, \text{ for } 1 \leq i,j \leq n \text{ and } i \neq j   
$$
where $\vec{B_{i,\cdot}}$ is the $i$-th row of $B$ and $\vec{A_{\cdot, j}}$ is the $j$-th column of $A$.
But here i am kind of stuck.

Comment: Is $m<n$ or $m>n$ or $m=n$ or do we have to consider all cases?

Comment: I'd say the most interesting cases are the ones where $m \geq n$

Comment: In those cases, you cannot say much about $A$ and $B$: Take any $n\times m$ matrix $B$ with full rank. It is then trivial to find an $m\times n$ matrix $C$ such that $BC = I_n$, for example $C=B^T(BB^T)^{-1}.$ Set $A=C(\lambda_1\cdot I_n+\lambda_2\cdot \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^T).$ In the same way, you can show that you cannot say much about $A,$ because you can use the same argument.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, how about cases where they don‘t have full rank? It should still be possible to find a way to get such a result right?

Comment: The rank of the product of two matrices cannot exceed the rank of any of the factors. If the rank of $A$ or $B$ is less than $n$, you get a singular matrix. This is possible only if $\lambda_1 = 0$ or $\lambda_1+n\lambda_2=0.$ As long as $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ can be any combination of values without any additional restrictions, $A$ and $B$ must have full rank.

Comment: @elson This is a strange question with many possible answers. It might help if you would tell us what it is that you plan on doing with these matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: They represent weights of a neural network and i want to figure out what is possible while still maintaining this property

Comment: Yes but its still possible to obtain such a matrix even if one of the two matrices doesnt have full rank for example:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & -0 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &-1 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$